# Spacing between letters (ligature)

Tags: kerning, letterspacing

I noticed today how the spacing between letters are for fl/fi. Is this good a sign of typography?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
fluid - Fluid

fish - Fish
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What error do you mean? These just look like the fl/fi ligatures in CM to me.

Comment: The "f" is overlapping "i" and "l". Try with "Office". Here the first "f" overlap the second one! Do you get the same contraction @JosephWright?

Comment: Office doesn't do ligatures without some setting changes, so the result will of course be different (and wrong in Office). Perhaps compare the 'famous' case in English where a ligature should be suppressed: `shelfful - shelf\kern0pt ful`

Comment: Can see that it has nothing to do with the update. Same feature in older documents. Is this the desired graphical result?

Comment: yes all reasonable typesetting systems have always done that for hundreds of years.

Comment: Since when is Office a reference for typography?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a `ligature` and is a sign of good typography. The standard ligatures  for TeX are `fi, fl,ffi,ffl`, but there's also `fj` and the old  style ligatures `st`and `ct`, and some others, depending on the font. They're most easily accessed with `fontspec` and `xelatex`. Here is an example, with `Latin Modern`, `erewhon` (an extension of `Adobe Utopia`) and `Sabon Next LT Pro` (the latter is a commercial font, the former two are in TeX Live and MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\erewhon{erewhon}[Ligatures=Rare]
\newfontfamily\otherfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}[Ligatures=Rare]

\begin{document}

fluid - Fluid - fjord - baffled - suffix

fish - Fish - special act - fb - fk
\bigskip

\erewhon

fluid - Fluid - fjord - baffled - suffix

fish - Fish - special act - fb - fk
\bigskip

\otherfont

fluid - Fluid - fjord - baffled - suffix

fish - Fish - special act - fb - fk
\vskip1 cm


\end{document}
```

[image]